# Set paper-input font size in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I've attempted to style a paper-input element in my app using the CSS mixing described in the [Polymer Guides](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) but I can't quite get it to work for font size and paper-input.

I've tried the following custom element:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
  <style>
    :host {
      --paper-input-container-input {
        font-size: 30px;
      };
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-input></paper-input>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-element',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When running this, the font size remains unchanged.   Has anyone been able to modify paper-input's font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a colon (`:`) in the style, it should be like this

```
<style>
:host {
  --paper-input-container-input: {
    font-size: 30px;
  };
}
</style>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tmva6q81/)

Comment: Good grief I can't believe that's what I've been missing this entire time!  Thanks so much!